# How to do this selection with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have the following html

```
<button class="a b ">
    <div class="example">
        example
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <svg aria-label="somelabel"></svg>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button class="a b ">
   fake button
</button>
```

and want to select all the buttons that contain that have both classes a and b and also contain the svg with aria-label "somelabel".

In my example the result of xpath should be only the first button.

What I tried without success:

```
//button[@class='a b']*[ancestor::svg[@aria-label='somelabel]]
```

I also tried initially another xpath but is giving me back both buttons and I don't want this result:
`//button[@class='a b']`

Any idea how to write the xpath for this use case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`<svg>` is a child (not ancestor) of `<button>`, so I think you may be looking for

```
//button[contains(@class,'a b')][.//svg[@aria-label='somelabel']]
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not working for me

Comment: @KristiJorgji It does work with your sample xml; [take a look here](http://xpather.com/UT5wZDJr).